# Spring Boot - Run a WAR which is injected as a dependency as a standalone JAR

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to move a Spring WebMVC project to containerless architecture. I thought to start by having a simple Spring Boot project which only needs to start the embedded WAR file, and inject all the beans as normal. In my `Application.java` class, I have the following:

```
package demo.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:beans/beans.xml")
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

In my `pom.xml`, I have included the Spring WebMVC project as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.other.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>CoolWARApplication</artifactId>
        <version>${app.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

My full pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.springbootapp</groupId>
<artifactId>springbootapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <app.version>3.0.27-SNAPSHOT</app.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.other.app</groupId>
        <artifactId>CoolWARApplication</artifactId>
        <version>${app.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>


</project>
```

In my project structure in Eclipse, I can see this project and all of its dependencies being pulled in. However, when I start the Spring Boot app, I get the following error:

`org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.`

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I thought that importing the WebMVC project as a dependency and injecting its beans into the Spring Boot application would run the project as normal, only inside a standalone JAR file. Is it advisable, or even possible, to do the above as described?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your pom ? It would be useful to see what Spring Boot Starter poms you have included as without for example the starter web one you won't have an embedded servlet container such as Tomcat or Jetty.

Comment: I realized that I had forgotten to include Tomcat, so I added it, however I am getting a new error: `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]:`

Comment: Why? Just introduce Spring Boot to your WAR don't try to add the war as dependency and wrap it in Spring Boot, that will only complicate things. Just make your war build with Spring Boot (that way you can have both deployment as is and an executable jar before moving to a jar).